# Unable to Debug .NET Blazor MAUI on host Windows machine "This project needs to be deployed before we can debug"

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, maui

OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro

OS Version:                10.0.19044 N/A Build 19044

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.8.0

It works ok when debugging on my connected android device, but
**getting this error when trying to debug on windows:**
[image]

```
DEP1000: Cannot copy file "C:\Users\USER\.nuget\packages\microsoft.fluentui.aspnetcore.components\4.0.0\staticwebassets\Components\HorizontalScroll\FluentHorizontalScroll.razor.js" to layout "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Repositories\attendance-roll-app\AttendanceRollApp\AttendanceRollApp\bin\Debug\net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\wwwroot\_content\Microsoft.FluentUI.AspNetCore.Components\Components\HorizontalScroll\FluentHorizontalScroll.razor.js". DirectoryNotFoundException - Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\USER\Documents\Repositories\attendance-roll-app\AttendanceRollApp\AttendanceRollApp\bin\Debug\net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\wwwroot\_content\Microsoft.FluentUI.AspNetCore.Components\Components\HorizontalScroll\FluentHorizontalScroll.razor.js'.
```

This is my project structure. I'm using a Razor library project to try to reuse the UI later.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error screenshot you provided, you need to check the Deploy option of the Project contexts in `Configuration Manager` under Build option like below. Also, you can try to delete obj and bin folders.

[image]

> DEP1000: Cannot copy file
> "C:\Users\USER.nuget\packages\microsoft.fluentui.aspnetcore.components

For this error, this could be related with the path of the project is too long. You can try to copy the project to C:\ to see if it works.

Comment: I forgot to mention this, but the Deploy option is checked. I'll try what u say about the path

Comment: It worked! Do you know how to fix this without changnig the path? I tried modifying the registry on windows, and restarting. Even modifying the app.manifest for the maui app to enable longpath aware, but no success.

Comment: Thanks for the update, as I said to fix the issue, you need a shorter file path for the project as a temporary workaround. And it's related with this existing issue:[MAUI Blazor app with long reference paths fails to Deploy on Windows
#10068](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10068)